# how to make custom map presentation

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I would like in my map to make a custom look of my map. My goal is to make everything black, and show only streets. The best example is ingress game (example below)

How they achived that ? I didn't find any materials that would describe how to make such big customization and animated markers

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ingress is done using Libgdx so its not using google-maps in the "easy way" you would like to use.
In any case, you could do that by removing the googlemaps tiles and have something that gives you black tiles and streets or only streets (and create the black by yourself).
This should be a custom tileoverlay that you put as background.
Unfortunately i can't give code, it's something that I don't know if it is already done somewhere...